# Object property not changing as expected when using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I'm trying to play some around with classes in C++. Coming from a Java world, they're slightly different.

What I'm trying to do should be obvious: I have a class named `SomeClass`, which holds a single `int`. Then I have a class named `A`, which

```
// Create a class holding just an integer.
class SomeClass {
    public:

        int _value;

        SomeClass(int value) {
            this->_value = value;
        }
};

class A {

    private:
        // The property _someClassPointer holds a pointer to a SomeClass object.
        SomeClass *_someClassPointer;
    public:

        // We can set a SomeClass instance as a property of the A class.
        void setSomeClass(SomeClass *someClassPointer) {
            // It copies the local pointer value to the property.
            this->_someClassPointer = someClassPointer;
        }

        // We can retrieve the integer that the SomeClass instance holds.
        // We're assuming _someClassPointer does not point to NULL.
        int getValueOfSomeClass() {
            this->_someClassPointer->_value;
        }
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    // Instantiate SomeClass object with int(5) argument
    SomeClass someClass(5);

    Serial.println(someClass._value); // It prints 5, as expected

    // Instantiate an A object by its default constructor
    A a;

    // Pass the address of someClass to the method
    a.setSomeClass(&someClass);

    // Set the value of someClass to 6
    someClass._value = 6;

    Serial.println(a.getValueOfSomeClass()); // It prints 0
}
```

How come `0` is printed instead of `6`?

Comment: Concerning the signatures, those should go in a different question. But that kind of thing has been asked ans answered many times. Search for "pass by value"  "pass by reference" and "pointers".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Question 1 is a type and Question 2 is a duplicate. (Also, two independent questions as one)

Comment: @gha.st "Type" — you mean "typo"?

Comment: @MCEmperor Oh great, my "typo" has a typo >.<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is not returning a value.

```
int getValueOfSomeClass() {
    return this->_someClassPointer->_value;
}
```

EDIT:
I should mention that you can remove the 'this->' because it is implied in non-static method.

```
int getValueOfSomeClass() {
    return _someClassPointer->_value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd Question: It's the diference between passing arguments by value, by reference and by pointer. Its a little tricky, but you can find a lot of info in the web about this topic.